# Spying Elements in Blue Prism - HTML

Tags: element, spying

I am attempting to spy elements of a web page in Blue Prism however I am getting the below error message.

> System.ApplicationException: Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155)
>      at BluePrism.AMI.clsAMI.Spy(clsElementTypeInfo& elementType, List`1& identifiers)
>      at Automate.frmIntegrationAssistant.HandleSpyOrLaunchClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)

please can someone assist?

- application is set to (Browser Based Application)
- App Mod does attach successfully

Comment: It looks like your BP is faulty or otherwise missing software component

Answer (score 0):

On which mode are you trying to spy?

Go for accessibility mode. That might help.

Answer (score -1):

Web application -> html mode use for spy elements and now recheck again and do spy elements as html mode (ctrl+left button)